# Postgis - extrude a polygon

Tags: postgis, polygon-creation, extrude

I want to extrude a polygon shape in postgis to create a pseudo 3D effect. To this end I have written a crude function to achieve it. This is very much test code and it creates a new Y vertice for each point on the polygon and then closes it by returning to the original point:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.extrude_polygon(wkb_geometry_param geometry, height integer, simplify boolean DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS geometry AS
 $BODY$
DECLARE
f int;
ret_geom geometry;
wkb_geometry geometry;
BEGIN

--convert polygon to linestring
IF ST_GeometryType(wkb_geometry_param) != 'ST_Polygon' THEN 
    RETURN NULL;
END IF;

IF simplify THEN
    wkb_geometry =         ST_Simplify(ST_Transform(ST_Exteriorring(wkb_geometry_param), 27700), 0.5);
ELSE
wkb_geometry = ST_Transform(ST_Exteriorring(wkb_geometry_param), 27700);
END IF;

--initialise output geometry
ret_geom =ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry,1),ST_PointN(wkb_geometry,1));

--Move first point to up

SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom,
      ST_MakePoint(ST_X(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, 1)), 
                   ST_Y(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, 1)) + height)
) into ret_geom;

FOR f IN 1..ST_NPoints(wkb_geometry) LOOP
    IF f < ST_NPoints(wkb_geometry) THEN
    --across to next high point
    SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom,
               ST_MakePoint(ST_X(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, f + 1)), 
               ST_Y(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, f + 1)) + height)
    ) into ret_geom;
    --down to next point
    SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom, ST_PointN(wkb_geometry,f + 1)) into ret_geom;
    --back to last point
    SELECT  ST_AddPoint(ret_geom, ST_PointN(wkb_geometry,f)) into ret_geom;
    --back then up again
    SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom, ST_PointN(wkb_geometry,f + 1)) into ret_geom;
    SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom,
               ST_MakePoint(ST_X(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, f + 1)), 
               ST_Y(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, f + 1)) + height)
    ) into ret_geom;
ELSE
    --across to first high point
    SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom,
               ST_MakePoint(ST_X(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, 1)), 
               ST_Y(ST_PointN(wkb_geometry, 1)) + height)
           ) into ret_geom;

    SELECT ST_AddPoint(ret_geom, ST_PointN(wkb_geometry,1)) into ret_geom;

END IF;
END LOOP;

RETURN ST_Buffer(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePolygon(ret_geom),10), -10);


END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

It works with simple polygons but has problems with interior rings, but the main issue is that it is really slow. I need to output the resultant shape as a polygon that can be shaded and rendered in mapserver. Hence the buffer operations at the end which is the only way I know of reducing the shape to it's outline.

The end result will be an extruded shape representing the original polygon. I can then offset the original polygon by the same extrusion distance and place it on top to make the roof.
[image]

I considered using the ST_Extrude function in postgis-2.1.1 BUT this creates a ST_PolyhedralSurface type and I am not able to render it in mapserver. As far as I can tell there is no way to create an outline of this either as ST_Buffer does not work with ST_polyhedralsurfaces.

So, my question is, can my function be improved? Or is there a better approach. The output needs to look as per the diagram which I created by placing the offset polygon onto my extruded shape.

Comment: Great question! Perhaps you could output your data as KML for greater ease and flexibility with your extrusion? Here are some starting points : http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsKML.html, https://code.google.com/p/postexperiments/wiki/Extrude_Tesselate_and_Altitudemode_Support, http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html

Answer (score 3):

A fast solution for very simple polygons like circles. Results in 2 different tables which have to be rendered in the right direction.

-Table `poly` with input polygon(s)

-Table `poly_prj` with polygon from projected points

```
WITH points AS (
  SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS geom 
FROM poly
  SELECT 
    ST_MakePolygon(
      ST_MakeLine(
        ST_Project(geom, 5000, radians(0.0))::geometry)) AS geom 
  FROM points;
```

-Table `cvx` with a convex hull of the 2 features.

Table `poly_prj` has to be on top of the table `cvx`.

After that you can play with the new fill options in QGIS 2.10!

[image]